What does "こんなものか" here mean?
.... 追跡者は赤で足止めを喰らっているようだ。背中で状況を把握しながらこんなものかと肩透かしされた気分になった。
（気にしすぎだったかな）
The character thinks he's being followed... so he starts to run to shake off his pursuer.
He watis for the red light and runs and so he notices the pursuers stopped.
。背中で状況を把握しながら as I grasp the situation behind my back...
What does 肩透かしされた actually mean?  is he wondering if it was just all in his head?


こんなものか is a common idiom meaning "Is this all?"
肩透かし means "letdown" or "disappointment (after building up expectations)". It's more common to say 肩透かしを食らう than 肩透かしされる, but the basic meaning remains the same.


こんなものかと肩透かしされた気分になった。
I felt somewhat let down, thinking "Is that all?"

